# Stuck at searching and removing from array

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

Must add sales rep name, amount, calculate commission, and remove sales rep and sale from array.

I'm struggling with the `searchSeller` method and have made no progress in over 24hrs.

```
static string SearchSeller(int[] sellerSales, string[] sellerNames, int sellerCount,
                           ref string salesRep)
{
    int index = 0;
    bool found = false;

    while (!found && index < sellerCount)
    {
        if (salesRep = sellerNames[index])
            found = true;
        else
            index++;
    }
    if (!found)
        index = -1;
    return sellerNames[index];
}
```

The issue seems to be somewhere in the line:

```
if (salesRep = sellerNames[index])
```

Error says:

> cannot convert string to bool.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a great first question. :)

Comment: Btw you should check [`Array.FindIndex()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.findindex?view=netframework-4.7.2) or maybe Linq's Enumerable.First(), Enumerable.Single() and Enumerable.Contains . [Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XduigC)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change

```
 if (salesRep = sellerNames[index])
```

to

```
 if (salesRep == sellerNames[index])
```

single `=` will assign `sellerNames[index]` to `salesRep` while `==` is for comparison

And as you have already given the text to search, so returning same value does not have any point, I think you will want to return its index right?

```
return index; //indested of return sellerNames[index];
```

And you function should return int:

```
static int SearchSeller(int[] sellerSales, string[] sellerNames, int sellerCount, ref string salesRep)
```

Comment: wow.  i have litterely been going crazy over this for over a day now! the simplest of things.  Thank you kindly!!

Comment: @electric.arc: you can simplify your logic: `int index = 0; while (index < sellerCount)
    {
        if (salesRep == sellerNames[index]) return index;
        index++;
    }
    return -1;`